# "Address family not supported by protocol family" error

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

When ever I try to login to a FTB server it says:

> Connection Lost: Address family not supported by protocol family: connect: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol family: connect.

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: what address are you putting in for the server?

Comment: Ensure that you are on the same version and also, as TZHX asked, what address are you using?

Comment: Well When I load up the consle and lancher in the consle it says the same exact thing about 15 times

Comment: Also, did you try putting the message into search engines, [find this post](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/587899-failed-to-launch-fatal-error-occured-4/page__gopid__7776037#entry7776037), and see if that was the problem & solution before posting? If not, does that fix it?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a Java problem. Try uninstalling Java and re-installing Java again.

Answer (score 0):

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17208734/321973) suggests Java7 may try some (defunct?) IPv6-stuff, which you can apparently disable by adding the switch `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` to your `java -jar minecraft.jar` call; [or more permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11851560/321973) and easier by running the line `setx _JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` from a command prompt. I do of course assume you already made sure your antivirus is not to blame...